# Converting String to Date using SimpleDateFormat returns incorrect format

Tags: java, android, datetime, jdbc, simpledateformat

I have a String `s` date in following format `05-10-2020`

I want to convert this String to Date in following format `dd-MM-yyyy`
so I can use it in below query for my Sqlite db

```
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String s = app.getDate(); // returns "05-10-2020"
Date date = simpledateformat.parse(s);
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM User Where Date !=" + date;
```

But date is returns date in follwoing format `Mon Oct 05 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020`

Comment: What else did you expect? This is the correct date.

Comment: My date in db is of type DateTime I need to compare it with same data type which is also DateTime that what I'm trying to do. converting the String to Date object so I can compare the two.Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: can you try `simpledateformat.format(s);` , just a thought

Comment: @aryanagarwal format() returns a String

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `PreparedStatement` with `LocalDate` as this:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(app.getDate(),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"));
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM User Where Date != ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery)) {
    ps.setObject (1, ld);
    // ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why do I have to use PreparedStatement

Comment: @r_via to avoid SQL Injection and Syntax errors

Comment: @r_via - Check [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, this answer teaches you another good thing [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements for RDBMS work. From your third line on, try:

> PreparedStatement selectQuery = connectionObj.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM User Where Date != ?");

> selectQuery.setDate(1, date);

> ResultSet res = selectQuery.executeQuery();

> res.next();

> // manipulate the resultset to your heart's content

Answer (score 0):

It will provide a lean solution. You can dynamically adjust it to your code.

```
String dateStr = "Mon Oct 05 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020";
 
DateFormat formatOne= new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
DateFormat formatSecond= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(formatSecond.format(formatOne.parse(dateStr)));
```

You can use it at the relevant place in your project.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/XiNgMk)

Comment: My String is in the following format "05-10-2020" also the code above returns 04-10-2020 it should be 05-10-2020